# Radio button multiple issue with list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select the text, on text select or list select the radio button should be selected automatically by the jquery code but its looping between the last two radio buttons only

note: i want only one selection should be made between 5 radio button on list selection

Here is my code:

```js
 $('.saved_card .customerid').click(function() {                            
        $('.glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        $('.saved_card .selected_radio').removeClass('selected_radio');
        $("i", this).toggleClass('glyphicon-ok');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected_radio');
        $('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').prop("checked", true);    
});
```

And [my jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/svp4msfu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use label tag like André Senra says

```js
$('.saved_card .customerid').click(function() {

  $('.glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
  $(this).addClass('glyphicon-ok');
  $('.selected_radio').removeClass('selected_radio');
  $(this).addClass('selected_radio');

  $('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", false);
  $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);

});
```

```css
ul.saved_card li i {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #f00f64;
}
ul.saved_card li {
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="saved_card">
  <li class="customerid">
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust1" id="cust1">Savings account-***4443<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></i>
  </li>

  <li class="customerid">
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust2" id="cust2" checked>Savings account-***4212<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
  </li>

  <li class="customerid">
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust3" id="cust3" checked>Savings account-***4212<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
  </li>

  <li class="customerid">
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust4" id="cust4" checked>Savings account-***4212<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
  </li>

  <li class="customerid">
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust5" id="cust5" checked>Savings account-***4212<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**And jsfiddle is here**

https://jsfiddle.net/svp4msfu/1/

Answer (score 2):

Please use HTML5 **label** element like this:

```
<ul class="saved_card">
    <li class="customerid">
        <label for="cust1">Savings account-***4443<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust1" id="cust1">
    </li>
    <li class="customerid">
        <label for="cust2">Savings account-***4443<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" name="customer" value="cust2" id="cust2">
    </li>
</ul>
```

You don't need javascript to do this.

Comment: **Always** prefer the native HTML approach, when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Change last line to this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]', $(this)).not(':checked').prop("checked", true);
```

Though you should rather do as Andre suggests, and use a label.